# How can I prevent the widget rebuilding when opening the keyboard

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, build, rebuild

i have main `StatefulWidget` which contains several `StatefulWidget` classes by it's `TabBarView`
like following

```
    class MyNainClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyNainClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyNainClass> createState() => _MyNainClassState();
}

class _MyNainClassState extends State<MyNainClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          TextField() // here is the problem 
        ],
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          // Here i have several `StatefulWidget` as tabs like 4 ones
          // Note: that per claas is contains heavy work code  !
          MyStatefulWidget1(),
          MyStatefulWidget2(),
          MyStatefulWidget3(),
          MyStatefulWidget4(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

well, now every time user tabbed on the `TextField` then keyboard pops up so it is causes widget rebuilding , that's means all my classes into `TabBarView` do rebuild too .

in the fact even if user tabbed any other `TextField` it also rebuild the whole classes .

This was a huge disappointment to me after I studied a lot of provider and i completely not using `setState` to make my app good with performance .

i have read many similar questions like mine but it look like there no solution with this issue

that's happen because `Scaffold` depends on `MediaQuesry` with causes more resize of screen for keyboard .
i tried with `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` set to false but it still des not prevent unwanted rebuild when keyboard pops up .

my `AppBar` search bar is very active in my app and i can't imagine what the horrible results will be effect to my app performance if users tab on it every time special i have big classes will be rebuild too .

any solution to How prevent widget rebuilding when keyboard pops up are most welcome
thank you

Comment: Seems like a state-management library will do you good. Use a stateless widget in combination with either Riverpod, Provider or Getx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried using "const TabBarView(..." ?

Comment: thank you so mush , it is really prevent rebuild as wanted ,, ! i really didn't imagine that const will do all this